# Arduino Uno does not want to write variable

Tags: c++, arduino

I am writing a small sketch to read sensor values and print them on a LCD screen.
This worked great until now, I can't remember having changed anything but suddenly my Arduino doesn't want to change the value of the ringbuf variable any more, it's now always at 8224.

These are the most relevant parts of the code:

```
const int RING_SIZE = 5;
double ringbuf[RING_SIZE]; // array for the ring buffer
unsigned int ringpos = 0; // position in the ring buffer - this will always be 8224 for some reason

// in loop()

ringbuf[ringpos] = readSensor();
ringpos++;
if (ringpos >= RING_SIZE) {
    ringpos = 0;
}
```

Here is the whole code:

```c
#include <Wire.h>

#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#include <Keypad.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int readpin = A2;
int irpin = 9;
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 20;
int buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
const int RING_SIZE = 5;
unsigned int ringpos = 0;
double ringbuf[RING_SIZE];
unsigned long lastRedTime = millis();
char text[20];

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;
const unsigned long BACKLIGHT_DURATION = 5000;
const double THRESHOLD = 245;

const double wattPerTurn = 1.666666667;
double lastUsage = 0;
bool currentState = LOW;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {{'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[] = {5, 4, 3, 2};
byte colPins[] = {8, 7, 6};
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x20, 16, 2);

unsigned long lastKey = millis();
int turns = 0;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.home();

  pinMode(irpin, OUTPUT);
  analogReference(DEFAULT);
  digitalWrite(irpin, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(ringpos);
  Serial.println();
  ringbuf[ringpos] = readSensor();
  ringpos++;
  if (ringpos >= RING_SIZE) {
    ringpos = 0;
  }

  double value = getAverage();
  if (value < THRESHOLD && currentState == HIGH) {
    currentState = LOW;

    lastUsage = wattPerTurn / (double) ((millis() - lastRedTime) / 1000) * (double) 3600;

    turns ++;
    lastRedTime = millis();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
    lcd.print("rot");
  }
  if (value > THRESHOLD && currentState == LOW) {
    currentState = HIGH;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
    lcd.print("silber");
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

  sprintf(text, "%i W", lastUsage);
  lcd.print(text);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  sprintf(text, "s: %i, t: %i Wh   ", (int) value, (int) (((double) turns) * wattPerTurn));
  lcd.print(text);

  delay(20);
}

double getRelative(int r) {
  int v = ringpos + r;
  while (v < 0) {
    v += RING_SIZE;
  }
  while (v >= RING_SIZE) {
    v -= RING_SIZE;
  }
  return ringbuf[v];
}

double getAverage() {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < RING_SIZE; i++) {
    sum += ringbuf[i];
  }
  return sum / (double) RING_SIZE;
}

double readSensor() {
  for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
    buf[i] = analogRead(readpin);
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
    sum += buf[i];
  }

  return (double) sum / (double) BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

I might have missed something very stupid but I can't tell why this would just stop working. I also tested this on another Arduino, the same thing happens.

Comment: Well this is super weird because when I put the declaration of ringpos before the array, like this:

    unsigned int ringpos = 0;
    double ringbuf[RING_SIZE];

it does work. Why this happens is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the question to contain all relevant code directly instead of linking to it on pastie. The error is not in the code you showed here, it is that your `text` variable

```
char text[10];
```

is much too short for the

```
sprintf(text, "s: %i, t: %i Wh   ", (int) value, (int) (((double) turns) * wattPerTurn));
```

you do later, so this writes beyond `text` over the variables that happen to lie behind `text` in RAM. Presumably, `ringpos` happens to be among those overwritten in one case but not the other, but of course this causes UB, and whichever way it behaves is not reliable.

To fix it, make `text` large enough.

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to paste the whole code here because It thought that would be unreadable

Comment: I understand the sentiment, and I understand that building [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s for problems with Arduino sketches is not quite as useful as with PC code because you'd need the hardware to reproduce the problem, but it is important that the question contains all the information that is needed to answer it, and narrowing down the problem before asking is always appreciated. For now, I'd say: just append the pastie code to the question. In the future: when you believe that posting the whole code would be unreadable, try to cut out irrelevant bits until it is short enough.